# Ignoring 301/2 in Server Replay

Tags: mitmproxy

I'm recording a flow that triggers a SSO (SAML) on initial page load

When I do the server playback I don't want this part ignored so that all I see is the status of the ui in the browser after the SSO callback has redirected to the UI

It doesn't appear to be a way to filter this out. I tried ignoring the host but then it just triggers a live request and this host is not accessible.

Is there somehow a way to ignore the recording in a flow of particular redirects as in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the docs. the best option I came up with is to remove the flows from the recorded session altogether using a filter e.g.

```
# normal capture
./mitmdump -w outfile

# after session transform capture with a filter
# match all non redirect requests on the particular domain 
./mitmdump -nr ./outfile -w outfile2 "!(~c 301 | ~c 302) & ~u ^https://mytest-app.io.*$"
```